# OMPython File Specification to run OMCSessionZMQ()

Tags: python, python-3.x, modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to run OMPython and I am experiencing an error running the example shown at https://openmodelica.org.

I can run the first line:

```
    from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
```

But when I try to run the second line:

```
    omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
```

I get the error:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

[Full traceback shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aGx3.png)

Has anyone experienced this error before? I believe I have my environment variables set correctly but I am not sure.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have OpenModelica installed?

Comment: Hello Adrian, yes I have OpenModelica installed. Does it need to be installed in a specific path?

Comment: No as it should create an environment variable called OPENMODELICAHOME which OMPython uses to find OpenModelica. I assume you are on Windows.

Comment: Yep. I am using Windows. There are two people on this project and the other has experienced the issue as well (also Windows). We are both new to OpenModelica but it is interesting that we are both running into this.

Comment: Do you get any python stack trace? That would help quite a bit.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I have added a screenshot of the traceback to the post. Hopefully it shows up clearly.

Comment: Can you have a look in the log file openmodelica.objid.*.log that you can find in %TEMP% directory? Maybe there is more information in there as as far as I can tell your system cannot find omc.exe at %OMPENMODELICAHOME%\bin\omc.exe.

Comment: The log is actually called openmodelica.port.some_random_numbers.log.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I was not able to find that file in the Temp directory. There was a log called openmodelica.port.0103b960b0a44110bdd3b6eca3913fe5, but it was empty.

As it happens I do not have a file called omc.exe. %OPENMODELICAHOME%\bin contains quite a few files, as well as folders for Modelica and OpenModelica, but no omc.

Comment: Then something went wrong with the install. Uninstall OpenModelica, restart and install it again.

Comment: Should I install it in a certain location? Also is there a specific location I should install OMPython?

Comment: Default location given by the installer is fine. The installer will create OPENMODELICAHOME to point to it. OMPython ends up inside the Python directory so no problem there either.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling fixed the issue! Somewhat odd since I had tried that previously - but I may have originally downloaded the stable development as opposed to the official release. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as provided by Adrian Pop was to uninstall, restart, and reinstall OpenModelica. This fixed the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).